# Custom structural directive creates too many elements

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I created my custom structural directive which should render the host element for each element in the passed array of items:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appItems]'
})
export class ItemsDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('appItemsOf')
  items: any[];

  constructor(private container: ViewContainerRef,
              private template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.container.clear();

    for (const item of this.items) {
      if (item) {
        this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {
          $implicit: item,
          index: this.items.indexOf(item)
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div *appItems="let item of items">
  Item: {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

Which, unfortunately, prints:

```
Item: 1
Item: 2
Item: 3
Item:
```

The last element is being created and rendered although the item array looks like:

```
items = [
    {
        name: '1'
    },
    {
        name: '2'
    },
    {
        name: '3'
    }
]
```

I created a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwatck[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwatck) showing this issue.

Why is this so and how should it be done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the following is done:

1. Directive instance is created
2. `NgOnChanges` is invoked
3. `NgOnInit` is invoked

So basically, once you create the the N-views for your collection, you create a further one during `NgOninit`, resulting in N+1 embedded views in your template being generated.

Simply remove the content of `NgOnInit`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought `ngOnChanges()` is being invoked after `ngOnInit()` therefore the "empty" element should have been at start, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating this in `ngOnInit`, as this this creating the extra one. After commenting this line the extra item will be gone.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
  }
```